# jq: format array of objects using map or from_entries

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have a massive JSON output like this

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "name": "Fields",
            "listFields": [
                [
                    "apple"
                ],
                [
                    "Banana__c"
                ]
            ],                    
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "apple",
                    "displayName": "Apple",
                    "color": "red",
                    "price": 20
                },
                {
                    "name": "Banana__c",
                    "displayName": "Banana",
                    "color": "yellow",
                    "price": 18
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "success": true
}
```

The desired output would be

```
{
   "fields": [
      "apple",
      "Banana__c"
   ],
   "Brand": "Kroger",
   "fruitNames": {
      "apple": "Apple",
      "Banana__c": "Banana"
   }
}
```

`{(.name)[], "Brand": "Kroger", "fruitNames" .fields|map({(.name): .displayName})}`
or
`.result[] | (.fields | map({key: "fields.name.\(.name)", value}) | from_entries)`
in https://jqplay.org/# throw syntax errors. Helpful manual here: https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/

Comment: it's invalid json

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest thanks for pointing that out. It was missing a comma and I added it

Comment: Still missing `]}` before `], "success": true}`.

Comment: @pmf that is very true. Thanks for the feedback. I totally missed that. Updated it

Comment: _"I have a massive JSON output ..."_  Massive how?  .. `"result"` array has many objects?  The other arrays have many objects?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
jq '.result[].fields | {"fields": map(.name), "Brand": "Kroger",
    "fruitNames": map({(.name): .displayName}) | add}' test.json
```

---

```
{
  "fields": [
    "apple",
    "Banana__c"
  ],
  "Brand": "Kroger",
  "fruitNames": {
    "apple": "Apple",
    "Banana__c": "Banana"
  }
}
```

Comment: Tip: `[.[].name]` can be written as `map(.name)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `from_entries`:

```bash
.result[].fields | map(.value = .displayName)
| {fields: map(.name), Brand: "Kroger", fruitNames: from_entries}
```

```json
{
  "fields": [
    "apple",
    "Banana__c"
  ],
  "Brand": "Kroger",
  "fruitNames": {
    "apple": "Apple",
    "Banana__c": "Banana"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/FZ3dpfM5LLP)

Answer (score 0):

Or even another way:

```
.result[].fields |
      {
       "fields": map(.name),
       "Brand": "Kroger",
       "fruitNames": (reduce .[] as $f ({}; . + {($f.name): $f.displayName}))
      }
```

Try it on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/Gf7PlspL3bK).